# DropDownList Viewbag with data from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a droplist with data from a Database. I am getting no results. Below is the code. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Controller:

```
DepartmentsConn dCon = new DepartmentsConn();
public ViewResult Employees(string Dept)
{
    ViewBag.Departments= new SelectList(dCon.Departments, "ID", "Dept");

    var employees = from m in db.Employees
                 where m.Dept == Dept ||Dept == null ||Dept == ""
                 select m;

     return View(employees.ToList());

}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Departments", ViewBag.Departments as SelectList)
```

Comment: Are you getting results in the controller and they are not getting to the view? Or no results in the controller at all?

Comment: Also, where are you populating the select list?  I see you instantiate the department select list, and make a separate employee list, but I dont see where you populate the instantiated department select list.

Comment: Well maybe that is my ignorance. Where should I be populating that? I am not seeing any results in the controller as far as I can tell

Comment: Apologies, you are correctly populating with the first parameter.  Allow me to look closer...  So i f you add a test line, something like var depts = dCon.Departments.ToList(), do you get any results?

Comment: Sorry - put that in the controller?

Comment: Yes, right above where you are populating the ViewBag.Departments.  Then put a breakpoint and see if var depts gets data.

Comment: OK, it is now working. Not sure what exactly was wrong, redid the controller and view. 

Quick question - is there a way to automatically redirect the  when a department is selected? @Html.DropDownList("Departments",ViewBag.Departments as SelectList)  ? So once I select Main is redirects to Employees(string Department) with the department I selected?

Comment: I would use jquery/ajax.  Im not super good at it, so my answer might be a bit convoluted, but it works.  I have posted below.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the second part about redirecting on click of the ddl.

First add a placeholder to the select list, so the user has to make a selection:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Departments", ViewBag.Departments as SelectList, "Select a department...")
```

Then add jquery that triggers on change, gets the Id value and sends it to the Controller:

```
    $(function () {

        $("#Departments").on("change", function () {
            var deptId = $(this).val();
            var routeVal = { Id: deptId };
            var url = '@Url.Action("Department", "Home")';

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: routeVal
            }).done(function (result) {
                window.location.href = result.newUrl;
            })
        })

    })
```

This is kind of a double jump, so I'm sure it can be improved on. Basically it gets the Id value, then sends it to a controller action called 'SetUrl' which returns a new url to the ajax function, which then directs the user to the new url in the .done() function.  In this case the new URL is Home/Department/1 which goes back to the controller to return the new view:

```
    public ActionResult Department(int Id)
    {
        // Get the department data for this ID
        // Fill a model then return it
        return View(model);
    }
```